# php custom function to check if values are blank

Tags: php, function

I would like to simplify this PHP process that checks if a value is blank.

If the value is blank, the variable gets set to null.  If not, the variable is set to the value.

In this case, I have successfully posted a jquery object (called criteria) to PHP for processing.  I then set the variables to the values in the object.  I use IF/ELSE statements to check if the object value is blank.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['criteria']))
  {
    $value = $_POST['criteria'];

    if($value['recentsq'] == ""){$recentsq = null;}else{$recentsq = $value['recentsq'];}  
    if($value['custname'] == ""){$custname = null;}else{$custname = $value['custname'];} 
    if($value['address'] == ""){$address = null;}else{$address = $value['address'];} 
  }
?>
```

I have quite a few of these values I need to check and set.

My question is how can I simplify this process by using a custom function?

Comment: now you have few solutions , check them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create a method like:

```
function customfunction($valueString){
    return ($valueString != '' ? $valueString : null);
}
```

in above method, i am using ternary operator.

In your example, you can just call this method like:

```
$recentsq = customfunction($value['recentsq']);
$custname = customfunction($value['custname']);
$address = customfunction($value['address']);
```

**Additional Point for future visitors:**

[According to PHP manual](https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), If you are using PHP 7:

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar
>   for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with
>   isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL;
>   otherwise it returns its second operand.

```
($valueString ?? null); // will use in method body
```

**equal to:**

```
($valueString != '' ? $valueString : null);
```

Comment: @JohnBeasley: sure :)

Comment: I am getting a 500 error which I was able to isolate to the function call: $recentsq = customfunction($value['recentsq']);  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JohnBeasley: check php error reporting, or dont know are u using framework

Comment: @Dharman: this is some additional info, if OP using php 7 then he can use, its body of `function customfunction($valueString){`

Comment: I am using 5.6.21

Comment: [PHP 7.0 is already dead](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)... unless I have moved back in time few years.

Comment: I get the same error using ($valueString != '' ?? $valueString)

Comment: @JohnBeasley You really need to upgrade some time soon. PHP 5.6 reached end of life. You are missing out on a lot of improvements. e.g. `??` does not exists prior to PHP 7

Comment: @JohnBeasley: if you are using PHP 5.6 then ?? will not work

Comment: @JohnBeasley: this will work for you `($valueString != '' ? $valueString : null);
`

Comment: @devpro The very last part of your answer is still wrong.

Comment: `$valueString ?? null` is equivalent to `isset($valueString) ? $valueString : null;` [Null-coalescing operator](https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: @Dharman: ahan, actually i am following my own example which i have mentioned in method's body.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use  directly the [Null coalescing operator](https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) from PHP 7

```
  if(isset($_POST['criteria']))
  {
    $value = $_POST['criteria'];

    $recentsq = $value['recentsq'] ?? null;
    $custname = $value['custname'] ?? null;
    $address = $value['address'] ?? null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use the following function get value from array and set a default initial value, by default null

```
function arrayValue($array, $key, $default = null)
{
   return (array_key_exists($key, $array) && $array[$key] !== '') ? $array[$key] :     $default;
}
```

Usage:

```
    $values = [
        'name' => 'David',
        'age' => 18,
        'sex' => '',
    ];
    $name = arrayValue($values, 'name');
    $age = arrayValue($values, 'age');
    $sex = arrayValue($values, 'sex', 'unknown');
    $country = arrayValue($values, 'country', 'unknown');

    print_r(
        [
            $name,
            $age,
            $sex,
            $country,
        ]
    );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => David
    [1] => 18
    [2] => unknown
    [3] => unknown
)
```

Like @christophe say since php7 can do something like

```
$name = $values['name'] ?? null;
$country = $values['country'] ?? 'unknown';
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `empty` function:

```
<?php

    $recentsq = empty($_POST['criteria']['recentsq']) ? null : $_POST['criteria']['recentsq'];
    $custname= empty($_POST['criteria']['custname']) ? null : $_POST['criteria']['custname'];
    $address= empty($_POST['criteria']['address']) ? null : $_POST['criteria']['address'];

?>
```

Then you don't even need to have separate `isset` checks.

Answer (score 0):

php function to check if input is blank.
its collected from laravel `blank` function

```
function is_blank($value) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (is_string($value)) {
        return trim($value) === '';
    }

    if (is_numeric($value) || is_bool($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($value instanceof Countable) {
        return count($value) === 0;
    }

    return empty($value);
}

// tests
$tests = [
    '', // true
    null, // true
    0, // false
    '0', // false
    '  ', // true
    [], // true
    1, // false
    'test' // false
];

foreach ($tests as $value) {
    echo json_encode($value) . ' is blank: ' . json_encode(is_blank($value)) . '<br>';
}
```